# minimum between columns in mysql with least(), give unpredicted result

Tags: mysql, minimum

In a view statement i try to add a column which gives me the minimum between between the user_value and friend_value column. the query doesn't give a error and gives me the desired result for 90% of the rows. sometime i find a row with for example user_value 35 and fried_value 119 and then the relation_value 119 while this supposed to be 35....

```
SELECT User, friend,  user_value, friend_value,  Least(user_value,friend_value) as relation_value



+----+------+--------+------------+--------------+----------------+
|  1 | User | friend | user_value | friend_value | relation_value |
|  2 | 1    | 2      | 35         | 50           | 35             |
|  3 | 1    | 4      | 35         | 20,5         | 20,5           |
|  4 | 1    | 29     | 10         | 15           | 10             |
|  5 | 1    | 30     | 35         | 37,5         | 35             |
|  6 | 1    | 31     | 35         | 40           | 35             |
|  7 | 1    | 32     | 35         | 10           | 10             |
|  8 | 1    | 33     | 35         | 16,66666666  | 16,66666666    |
|  9 | 1    | 34     | 35         | 119          | 119            |
| 10 | 1    | 35     | 35         | 8            | 35             |
| 11 | 1    | 36     | 35         | 120          | 120            |
+----+------+--------+------------+--------------+----------------+
```

i hope somebody can tell me where i can find the root of this problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I stare at your results, there is another possibility besides the "indeterminate" row problem.  That possibility is that your query is working, but the values are stored as characters rather than numbers.  That would explain the results.  You can fix this by converting the values to numbers.  Here is an easy way:

```
SELECT User, friend,  user_value, friend_value,
       Least(user_value + 0, friend_value + 0) as relation_value
```

Note that if the value contains a string that does not start with digits, it will have the value of `0`.

Moral of the story:  If you want to store numbers, use numeric data types, not character strings.

Comment: this does the trick, thanks! however, the values are round to 0 decimals, can i round them by 2? i think i have to find a way to let the view handle the values as doubles.

Comment: @Floria . . . Either try `+ 0.00` or `cast(user_value as decimal(10, 2))` to get them to two decimal places.

Comment: i tried  + 0.00 but it didn't had any effect. i try to use cast(user_value as decimal(10, 2)), but I don't seem to doing it correct. where do i place the cast statement? direct in the line with select? like cast(da1.value as decimal(10, 2)) as User_value

Comment: thanks! it works with  Cast(da1.value as decimal(10, 2)) as  user_value :)

Comment: sorry, one more question. how come that 16,666667 is now showed as 16.00 instead of 16,67? any suggestions? thanks :)

Comment: @Florian . . . My guess is that has to do with internationalization.  The comma is not normally considered a numeric character, so the conversion to a number stops there.  Probably the easiest fix (apart from using the correct datatypes!) is to do:  `replace(friend_value, ',', '.') + 0.00`.